# How can I get name for OLEDBConnection that feeds ListObject (Table)

Tags: vba, dax, tabular

With a user click I create a Table fed with DAX Query from ThisWorkbookDataModel. The code was recorded by macro-recorder and looks like this:

```
    Range("A9").Select

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=4, Source:=ActiveWorkbook. _
    Connections("Query - Unit___Student_unit_enrolment_d"), Destination:=Range( _
    "$A$9")).TableObject
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "DAXdetails"
End With


Range("DAXdetails[[#All]]").Select

With Selection.ListObject.TableObject.WorkbookConnection.OLEDBConnection
    .CommandText = Array( _
    "EVALUATE" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "CALCULATETABLE(" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Unit___Student_unit_enrolment_d" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "   ) ")
    .CommandType = xlCmdDAX
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ModelConnection_ExternalData_1").Refresh
```

The problem with this on-the-fly-creation is that if I have any other table already fed from ThisWorkbookDataModel in a Tabular DAX Query than this line

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ModelConnection_ExternalData_1").Refresh
```

refreshes that other table.

Can anyone suggest, how can I get the name of my connection for this Table DAXdetails that I'm creating on the fly -- to refresh it properly?

Answer (score 0):

By some manual trials and experiment I found the way to address that Connection by the index:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections(3).Refresh
```

Yet, if anyone has an idea how to get the name of Connection that feeds the DAX Tabular Query Table, it'll be of MUCH assistance.

Thank you!